# Select based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I’m trying to pull the fastest times for each exam and each user but just can’t seem to get the results I’m looking for.  For example, if I have a table as follows …

```
id  name    testname    min     sec     daterecorded        
1   joe     Exam1       3       22      2011-05-29
2   pat     Exam2       4       22      2011-06-01
3   pat     Exam2       6       26      2011-06-04
4   joe     Exam1       3       13      2011-06-02
5   pat     Exam1       5       44      2011-06-23
6   joe     Exam2       4       23      2011-06-22
```

I’m trying to get the following results if I run a query for the fastest times Joe has for any  exams he has taken

```
6   joe Exam2   4   23  2011-06-22
4   joe Exam1   3   13  2011-06-02
```

Or if I run for Pat I would get…

```
2   Pat Exam2   4   22  2011-06-01
5   Pat Exam1   5   44  2011-06-23
```

Comment: could you please provide column names?

Comment: did you forget to accept the answer, or was not it useful?

Answer (score 2):

From what your tables look like it is difficult to outline the solution, yet I'll try. Please note that it is T-SQL, but I believe that in such simple cases there should be no difference between MySQL and T-SQL. At least, you should grab the idea

```
SELECT mt.Id, mt.Name, mt.testname, mt.min, mt.sec, mt.daterecorderd
FROM MyTable mt JOIN (
    SELECT Name, testname, MIN(min*60 + sec) time
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Name, testname) s ON 
        mt.Name = s.Name AND 
        mt.testname = s.testname AND
        s.time = mt.min*60 + mt.sec
```

Comment: Seems to be pretty much how the MySQL guys do it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it, my limited testing seems to show that it works...

NOTICE: I used `mins` and `secs` as my column names to avoid problems with the built-in function MIN. I'm not sure it was needed, but give it a try if you want.

```
SELECT 
 name, 
 testName, 
 FLOOR(min(mins*60+secs)/60) as minutes, 
 FLOOR(min(60*mins + secs)%60) as seconds 
FROM 
 `theTable` 
WHERE 
 name = 'pat' 
GROUP BY testName
```